# Detect shake in forward direction

Tags: android

I am shaking mobile three times continue in x direction . i want to count the shake in forward direction. When i shake mobile in forward and comes in backward direction it count shake in both direction (forward and backward). Is there any way to this to count the shake in forward direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try looking at the raw accelerometer data to see what values you get for a 'forward shake'

Comment: i check its give me positive value